# What is PERC6i?

Tags: perc6

What is PERC6i? I understand that it's a type of hard drive or raid controller, what makes it special or is it just a brandname controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is the Dell PERC6i](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/Controllers/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=dhs&cs=cadhs1&sku=341-7043#Overview)

Basically, it's a SAS RAID controller.  What makes it special?  The things that I'd say are something of note are the following:

- Serial Attached SCSI
- PCI Express bus
- Supports up to 32 devices
- Supports RAID 0/1/5/6/10/50/60 (basically almost anything you might need)

Other than that, nothing really special.  Just a SAS RAID controller.

Comment: I don't know how the Perc6/i (and 5/i) compare to other contemporary SAS RAID controllers, but they are **much** faster than the U320 SCSI controllers in the previous generation Dells. They seem to be especially good at RAID5, and they also work very well with high end SATA disks like the Western Digital RE3 range. All in all they are a very good controller.